# Block WWW services using Windows 2008 firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, firewall

I have two network interfaces and I'd like to use one of them for WWW and the other for remote networking (RDP). How can I configure rules that will do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them different IP addresses and use the relevant IP addresses to access what you need.

You can block ports in addition to that, but the Firewall alone won't do what you need.

Comment: OK, they have different IPs that I can add to the rule scope. But how do I block everything except WWW/RDP?